# Spring Integration with MongoDB Queues: Custom Headers Lost

Tags: spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

I have an Spring Integration App for sending and receiving messages to/from a MongoDB queue, it works fine except for the message headers, at the sender I used:

```java
Message<PolicyEvent> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(myPayload)
                .setHeader("someHeader", "some value")
                .build();
messageGateway.sendEventMessage(message);
```

When the app receives the message, the only headers are default values(id, spanId, time, etc...).

Although I search on the web(documentation, Stackoverflow, etc), haven't been able to figure out why the custom headers are lost. My configuration is:

- Spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE
- Mongodb 4.0.3 community
- All configurations (including integration) are Java annotations(no xml).

Comment: You need to show the integration flow configuration downstream of the gateway (and the gateway itself) and exactly how you are interacting with Mongo.

Comment: I don't, as I said, is like any other standard configuration, whatever configuration you want(using java annotations) using spring integration, no matter what your configuration is, the headers are missing anyways

Comment: We are asking you about some MongoDb Spring Integration component configuration to let us to play with locally. Voted to close your question since it seems you you don't want to collaborate. Also as long as I know MongoDb, there is no `queue` abstraction. So, confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the code and the mongo endpoints currently don't support headers; I was not aware of that; feel free to open a new feature request in a GitHub issue.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/47d7bf3fe2faa99f9b80cbecbc01541b9d7782d8/spring-integration-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mongodb/outbound/MongoDbStoringMessageHandler.java#L118-L126

```java
    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
        Assert.isTrue(this.initialized, "This class is not yet initialized. Invoke its afterPropertiesSet() method");
        String collectionName = this.collectionNameExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, message, String.class);
        Assert.notNull(collectionName, "'collectionNameExpression' must not evaluate to null");

        Object payload = message.getPayload();

        this.mongoTemplate.save(payload, collectionName);
    }
```

Comment: could you add a link to where did you find out that conclusion please?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/47d7bf3fe2faa99f9b80cbecbc01541b9d7782d8/spring-integration-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mongodb/outbound/MongoDbStoringMessageHandler.java#L118-L126 But it would still be helpful if you could edit the question to show which components you are actually using.